# Gets out of bounds exception whenever my column is larger than my rows

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have been beating my head against the wall with my code. I finally got my code to allow me to input whatever numbers the user desires depending on how many rows and columns they want, but for some reason whenever I try to type in a larger column number than row number, I get an error. I've read over my loop tens of times, inserting -1 where I think the program is over counting, but it still won't work. I'm assuming this is the appropriate way to write a multidimensional array when it is completely dependent on the user, but if not, please tell me how to make my code more efficient. Thanks!

```
public class MultiPractice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Prompts user to insert desired rows and columns
        System.out.print("Enter how many rows you want in your array: ");
        int rowSize = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter hwo many columns you want in your array: ");
        int colSize = input.nextInt();

        // Asks users to insert desired numbers for the multi-array
        System.out.print("Enter " + (rowSize*colSize) + " integers: ");

        // Creates the multidimensional array
        int[][] multi = new int[rowSize][colSize];

        // Runs the for loop to put numbers where they belong in array
        for (int i = 0; i < multi.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < multi[colSize].length; j++) {
               multi[i][j] = input.nextInt();
               System.out.print(multi[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
       }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`multi[colSize].length` should be `multi[0].length` or `multi[i].length` (since you have a rectangular array, these have the same value).

`multi[colSize].length` is the length of row `colSize`. Therefore, if you have less than `colSize+1` rows (since they start from 0), this is out-of-bounds.

Comment: Thank you! That makes complete sense, I'm just having a lot of trouble finding good material on multidimensional arrays.

Answer (score 0):

It's .length that's screwing you up here. Multi[colSize].length is not the same as colSize; in fact, it's colSize + 1 (since length starts counting at 1).

**My Solution:** Instead of using `multi.length`, you can use `i < rowSize`. You can also swap out the `multi[colSize]` with `< colSize`.